# Facebook Unity SDK how to add like button for (for liking Facebook page)?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-like, facebook-unity-sdk

We want to add "like our Facebook page and get reward" to our Unity game.
We use Facebook Unity SDK (6.2.2).
Are there ways to add Like Button (for liking Facebook Page) with the Facebook Unity SDK?

Second, if no,  is it possible to add Like Button to my webpage (on my server), and "press" it programmatically from my unity app?
How to do this?

Comment: This plugin (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/24601) does it, so it should be possible...

Comment: @Paul-Jan  We can easily do through native sdk (I think developers of plugin did this). The question is about how to do this using **Unity** Facebook SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Facebook Unity SDK v6.2.2.
We simply sends the user to browser to our page.